# How do you publish a C# Windows app with Font Files correctly?

Tags: c#, fonts, installation, publishing

I have been stuck on this for quite some time. I have searched and found how to publish apps using the windows installer and the oneclick but this does not solve my problem. I created a very simple C# Windows app that takes the user's input and converts it to a different language. The language is letter-by-letter so there is no difficult pronunciation or structure that has to be taken into account. The program simply takes the input in a Times New Roman font and outputs it in the special font for the other language. It works great. Until I take it to another computer and install it only to find that the fonts are not there. **My question is how do you add the font files to the installer for the target system to use? Is this possible?**

Comment: Are you sure it is "Times New Roman"? It is a common font in all windows machines. May be you have issues with unicode? Did you try on a third comoputer?

Comment: It's not the Times that doesn't show up it's the font for the other language. Sorry. Forgot to add that part...

Comment: I don't think this is possible via click-once. Font's are really a system level thing.

Comment: You cannot install fonts with ClickOnce.  You'll need a regular installer.  Or rely on private fonts, like GDI+'s PrivateFontCollection.

Comment: @Hans why not turn PrivateFontCollection into an answer?

Comment: @Jon - Because I have no idea if it applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the true reason is that the font doesn't exist on the target machine, you can add a custom folder to your setup project called the `Fonts Folder`.  There you can place any font dependencies you want deployed with your project.

[image]

Comment: Where to find the 'setup project'? Using VS 2017 Express...

Answer (score 0):

You could include the font files, and an .ini file, with the installation and then use Microsoft's 'fontinst.exe' program to install them.

http://blog.stevienova.com/2007/09/28/installing-fonts-programmatically-on-windows/

http://www.google.com/search?q=installing+fonts+programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a custom installer. I use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for my applications, which I think is easy to work with.

There is a mechanism there for installing fonts. [Here's an example](http://it.megocollector.com/?p=72)