# Include font file in ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, fonts, clickonce

I am developing a ClickOnce winforms application, through visual studio 2017, and the main fonts used are Century Gothic and Segoe UI. The Segoe UI shows fine on most client PCs, however, Century Gothic only shows on those that also have Microsoft Office programs installed as it is included in them applications.

How can I include the font file in the ClickOnce application so that the user can download the font if they don't have it?

I have seen some answers that show how to access font from resource file, however this involves programmatically setting the font of each item. As I have designed my GUI through the designer, I would prefer to install the font onto the client's PC the first time if they don't have it.
Thanks!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353832/34092 work?

Comment: I used to deploy using a setup file, but due to the vast amount of updates I release, I deploy using ClickOnce so this doesn't really apply to my application. Thanks for the article though!

Comment: Maybe you can try to add font file as prerequisites to ClickOnce.Here is the documentation about [How to: Include prerequisites with a ClickOnce application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-include-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019). And here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263636/how-do-i-add-prerequisites-to-a-clickonce-application).

Comment: Have you checked that redistributing the font is legally allowed?

Comment: [Segoe UI font family - Licensing and redistribution info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#licensing-and-redistribution-info)

Comment: `Century Gothic` is the font the OP is interested in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include font to clickOnce installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124625/how-to-include-font-to-clickonce-installation)